# Program Flow and Event Listeners in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, events, air, event-handling

I'm having difficulty with program flow control when XML loads from an external source. I'm using Flash Builder 4.6

What should happen: use a loader. Listen for when it is loaded. When it fires the COMPLETE event, proceed.
What is happening: use a loader. Listen for when it is loaded. But before the COMPLETE event fires, program control returns to the calling class. So meanwhile, the program keeps going and throws an error because it is trying to access data which is null.

Three classes are involved:

- AdvocacyWiz.mxml - the base MXML file for this AIR mobile app
- Model.as - the model class
- myXMLLoader.as - class in which the loader loads data, then
  dispatches event when it's done.

I am calling a function setUpModel() in AdvocacyWiz.mxml once AdvocacyWiz.mxml is added to the stage. The setUpModel function in that class just looks like this:

```
Model.Instance.initialize(); //model is a singleton
```

The initialize function call invokes a loader in my XMLLoader.as class. That's where the event listener is left listening for the Complete event, which happens too late to prevent a null error from occurring.

EDIT: Here's the code --

In AdvocacyWiz.mxml (this fires first):

```
protected function addedToStageHandler(event:Event):void
{
   setUpModel();
   stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
   //... additional layout functions

private function setUpModel():void {    
   Model.Instance.initialize();
}
```

In Model (this fires second):

```
public function initialize():void {
    addEventListeners(); //this includes listener for StoriesXMLLoader.STORY_LOADED event which will be dispatched from the loader class.
    useExternalXML();   
    ...
    }

    private function useExternalXML():void
    {
        myLoader.getStory("1140");
    }
```

In the Loader class:

```
    public function getStory(storyId:String):void {
        var url:String = "http://mysite.com/whatever.xml";
        myLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
        myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, storyXMLLoaded);
        myLoader.load(new URLRequest(url)); 
    }

    private function storyXMLLoaded(e:Event):void {
        storyXML = new XML(e.target.data);
        dispatchEvent(new Event(StoriesXMLLoader.STORY_LOADED));
    }
```

What I want to do is call setUpModel() but not have flow returned to the mxml class until the model actually has data.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to redesign the flow of your application. Rely on the fact that data from the loader may not always be available. Consider the fact that what if the load could not retrieve the data at all. In this case you would want to display an error. Error handling should always be taken care of. With a little more effort you can achieve a lot more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you haven't provided any code, which would help considerably, but here's a few pointers.

> What should happen: use a loader. Listen for when it is loaded. When
>   it fires the COMPLETE event, proceed. What is happening: use a loader.
>   Listen for when it is loaded. But before the COMPLETE event fires,
>   **program control returns to the calling class**. So meanwhile, the
>   program keeps going and throws an error because it is trying to access
>   data which is null.

A lot of Flex is **asynchronous**. What this means is that when you try to load from the external source, program control immediately returns, as you noted.

In order to have the kind of program flow you want, you need to have the function that calls `load()` end after that call. Then, when the COMPLETE event listener fires, you can execute the remainder of the code that causes the null exception.

Comment: Not *all* of flex is asynchronous, but `Loader` is. Most of actionscript and flex is single threaded and synchronous.

Comment: @32bitkid Good clarification. A little brain dead this morning.

Comment: It might well be synchronous, but you can't count on the order in which it happens.

Comment: Code added. Given that the loader.load call resides in a function that comes from another class, how does one prevent the flow from returning there? By calling Loader.load in the mxml file?